# Missing interface in .net standard

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, .net-core-3.0, .net-standard-2.1

I am trying to implement port a class to my .net standard 2.1 library.  That class implements `ICustomTypeProvider` so that WPF can bind to some dynamic properties.  That interface is not available in .net standard.  I understand why this interface isn't there, but it's a simple interface to recreate on my own.  My question is: if I did recreate this interface in my .net standard library, then would there be a way that when I consumed that class in my WPF library, that it could be recognized as the predefined `ICustomTypeProvider` without the need of creating a wrapper class around it?  If I need to go the wrapper route that's cool, I was just wondering if I'm missing a cleaner way to implement this, but I didn't find anything.  Thanks for any insight.

Comment: This interface is available in net core 3. You should target that instead of netstandard. If you recreate the interface internally it will not be use by wpf framework.

Comment: I understand that, but the class is going to be consumed by other other .net standard libraries.  It needs to be in .net standard.  I'm pretty sure that I'm just going to need to create a wrapper in my .net core library.  It'll be a relatively easy.  I was just hoping there was some design pattern that could simplify this a bit so that I didn't have to commit to maintaining the wrapper along with the class.

Comment: You can also multi target between netcore and net standard, and only implement `ICustomTypeProvider` in net core (with `#IF xxx`)

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't think of that.  That is probably the better option.  Thanks.

Comment: An explanation for the down vote would have been nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate the interface yourself but it will not be used by the WPF framework.

However this interface is available in net core 3. You could target that instead of netstandard. If you need to produce a netstandard version I suggest you to use multitargeting between netcore and net standard, and only implement ICustomTypeProvider in net core (with #IF xxx). See below :

Project.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1;netcoreapp3.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Class1.cs

```
using System;

namespace lib
{
    public class Class1
#if NETCOREAPP3_0
    : System.Reflection.ICustomTypeProvider
#endif
    {
        public Type GetCustomType()
        {
#if !NETCOREAPP3_0
            throw new NotSupportedException();
#else
            return this.GetType(); // return your impl
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, on not netcoreapp3.0 target the interface will not exist. If you need it add it like that and remove previous #if lines:

```
#if !NETCOREAPP3_0
namespace System.Reflection
{
    public interface ICustomTypeProvider
    {
        Type GetCustomType ();
    }
}
#endif
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks for list of preprocessor symbols

Comment: This is very similar to how I implemented the solution, and it works great.  Thank you!